# Прозрачность в IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css

Как задать opacity в IE8 через css?
Я так понимаю opacity - оно из css3 и IE8 его не поддерживает, opacity: 0.5 - не работает.
Однако jquery умеет делать так $("#elem").css('opacity', '0.5') - и это работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filter:alpha(opacity=30);
/* синтаксис IE4.0*/
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50);
/* синтаксис IE5.5+ (является предпочтительным) */
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавить к нужным элементам класс

```
$('селектор').addClass('view')
```

и прописать в стилях

```
 .view {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```